# NumPy vs Cython - nested loop so slow?

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused how NumPy nested loop for 3D array is so slow in comparison with Cython.
I wrote trivial example.

Python/NumPy version:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(a,b,c):
    s=0
        for z in xrange(401):
        for y in xrange(401):
            for x in xrange(401):
                if a[z,y,x] == 0 and b[x,y,z] >= 0:
                    c[z,y,x] = 1
                    b[z,y,x] = z*y*x
                    s+=1
    return s

a = np.zeros((401,401,401), dtype=np.float32)
b = np.zeros((401,401,401), dtype=np.uint32)
c = np.zeros((401,401,401), dtype=np.uint8)

s = my_func(a,b,c)
```

Cythonized version:

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def my_func(np.float32_t[:,:,::1] a, np.uint32_t[:,:,::1] b, np.uint8_t[:,:,::1] c):
    cdef np.uint16_t z,y,x
    cdef np.uint32_t s = 0

    for z in range(401):
        for y in range(401):
            for x in range(401):
                if a[z,y,x] == 0 and b[x,y,z] >= 0:
                    c[z,y,x] = 1
                    b[z,y,x] = z*y*x
                    s = s+1
    return s
```

Cythonized version of `my_func()` runs approx. 6500x faster. Simpler function only with if-statement and array access can be even 10000x faster. Python version of `my_func()` takes 500.651 sec. to finish. Is iterating over relatively small 3D array so slow or I made some mistake in code?

Cython version 0.21.1, Python 2.7.5, GCC 4.8.1, Xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Can't really comment on the timing. But I wouldn't call a loop with ~65 million iterations "small", especially not in python. That's why `numpy` exists: you should let numpy do the looping over elements internally, rather than writing python loops over all array elements.

Comment: `@cython.boundscheck(False)` eliminates up to 1.5 billion bounds checks that get performed in your python for loop. That is 401^3 iterations * 4 array accesses * 3 indices per access * 2 checks per index. You can times that number by 2 since you've also disallowed negative indexing.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of Python for which Numba will give you an insane speedup, hardly without any coding. Just decorate the function with ```@numba.jit```.

Comment: Adding `@cython.nonecheck(False)` and `@cython.initializedcheck(False)` can improve performance.

Answer (score 5):

Python is an interpreted language. One of the benefits of compiling to machine code is the huge speedup you get, especially with things like nested loops.

I don't know what your expectations are, but all interpreted languages will be terribly slow at the things you are trying to do ([JIT compiling](http://pypy.org/) may help to some extent though).

The trick of getting good performance out of Numpy (or MATLAB or anything similar) is to avoid looping altogether and instead try to refactor your code into a few operations on large matrices. This way, the looping will take place in the (heavily optimized) machine code libraries instead of your Python code.

Comment: Numba can indeed JIT compile this Python code (using LLVM) and speed up the execution comparable to O2 in C. Yes we can beat even better performance out of Cython, but when an ```@numba.jit``` decorator will give so dramatic effects (try it!) it is hardly worth it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Krumelur, python loops are definitely slow. You can, however, use numpy to your advantage. Operations on entire arrays are quite fast, although you need a little ingenuity sometimes.

For instance, in your code, since your loop never reads the value in `b` after you modify it (I think? My head is a little fuzzy at the moment, so you'll definitely want to go through this), the following should be equivalent:

```
# Precalculate a matrix of x*y*z
tmp = np.indices(a.shape)
prod = (tmp[:,:,:,0] * tmp[:,:,:,1] * tmp[:,:,:,2]).T

# Use array-wide logical operations to compute c using a and the transpose of b
condition = np.logical_and(a == 0, b.T >= 0)

# Use condition to alter b and c only where condition is true
b[condition] = prod[condition]
c[condition] = 1

s = condition.sum()
```

So this does calculate `x*y*z` even in cases where the condition is false. You could probably avoid that if it turns out that is using lots of time, but it's likely not to be a significant factor.

Comment: Python loops are quite fast, actually. MATLAB and R loops are slow. NumPy indexing is slow, however, so doing a lot of that in a tight loop is not a good idea. But many scientists and engineers are coming to Python with preconceptions that are valid for MATLAB or R. Very often those do not apply to Python. That Python loops are 'slow' is one of those. Slower than a loop in C, yes, but not anything like a loop in R or MATLAB.

Comment: +1, you actually *did* the refactoring while I was too lazy :)

Comment: @SturlaMolden Not compared to C. While Python is probably a lot faster than MATLAB (I haven't used MATLAB in years so I wouldn't know), CPython is still interpreted and has the overhead associated with a highly dynamic language.

Answer (score 2):

For loop with numpy array in python is slow, you should use vector calculation as possible. If the algorithm need for loop for every elements in the array, here is some speedup hint.

`a[z,y,x]` is a numpy scalar value, calculation with numpy scalar values is very slow:

```
x = 3.0
%timeit x > 0

x = np.float64(3.0)
%timeit x > 0
```

the output on my pc with numpy 1.8.2, windows 7:

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 64.3 ns per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 657 ns per loop
```

you can use `item()` method to get the python value directly:

```
if a.item(z, y, x) == 0 and b.item(x, y, z) >= 0:
    ...
```

it can speedup the for loop about 8x.

Comment: Upgrading NumPy to version 1.9.0 and replacing `if a[z,y,x] == 0 and b[x,y,z] >= 0:` with `if a.item(z, y, x) == 0 and b.item(x, y, z) >= 0:` make noticeable difference. Now Python/NumPy version is only aprox. 600x slower in comparison to cythonized version.